# ArcGIS create profile graph from existing point feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, point, elevation, profile

I have a dataset of X,Y points (with a spacing of 20m between the points) that represents a flowline along a glacier. Next to dat, I got another point dataset of the glacier height with X,Y points and Z data for the elevation. What I want to do is extract the surface profile of the glacier along the flowline. Is there a way this can be done?

Attachment:
brown points = flowline (X,Y)
blue points = glacier shape with elevation (X,Y,Z)
TIN surface of the glacier elevation at the background

[image]

Comment: For your set up perhaps the easiest: sort brown points in descending order by elevation; convert points to line;interpolate line using elevation model; select line and use longsection tool from 3d analyst

Comment: Your points are in order along the glacier?  Populate the attribute table with the Z geometry.  Export the table to Excel.  Create the profile graph in Excel.